# GAE Go http post link

Tags: http, html, google-app-engine, post, go

I have a web app on GAE written in Go that [performs some calculations for the user](http://tpbitcalc.appspot.com/). The website communicates with the server through a simple HTTP Post. I want to let the user be able to share a link to the result they obtained without changing much in my Go code.

Is there some way to encode a HTTP Post message as a website url that would execute on the app engine as if the user sent the Post from the website?

How would the code for a button that would copy the proper link to user's clipboard (noting that the field values can change between page being loaded and user wanting the link, so hard-coding the values through GAE parser wouldn't work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a GET instead of a POST. That's the point of GET : it generates a bookmarkable URL.

GET should always be used for idempotent operations, unless the sent data contain secret information or are too large to be put into GET parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As in JB's answer you can use GET instead of post.
Or you can store the POST data in your datastore with an ID for each record. Then you can generated a url with that ID as a GET parameter.
When user clicks on that link your app reads your POST data from datastore, complete the request.

Check this link for copying link/text to users clipboard.

http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/06/javascript-copy-to-clipboard.html